# Cannot instantiate `BlobServiceClient` from within Azure App Services fastAPI application

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, fastapi, azure-appservice

I am trying to download data from an Azure Storage Account using azure-storage-blob's `BlobServiceClient` class.
When I run this snippet from a Jupyter notebook, I manage to retrieve the data without any problem:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(path, 'processed.csv')
```

`CONNECTION_STRING` is the connection string to my Azure Storage Account and `path`, the path to the `processed.csv` data onto this Storage Account.

However, when running the same script from within a fastAPI application deployed onto Azure App Services, I cannot manage to instantiate `BlobServiceClient`. Under the Jupyter notebook, `print(blob_service_client)` returns a BlobServiceClient object, under Azure App Services it returns null.

I am using `azure-storage-blob==12.13.1`, which is specified in my requirements.txt.

Comment: Where does CONNECTION_STRING come from? An environment variable? Hard coded?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. CONNECTION_STRING is an environment variable. I was able to print it in the swagger so I confirm that it is being read properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below sample code to get the file data from blob.

```py
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def  read_root():
return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/items")
def  download_blob():
    try:
        name = "<Filename>"
        container_name = "<Container Name."
        connect_str = "<Connection String>"
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=name)
        print(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
        return {"File downloaded":blob_client.download_blob().readall()}

    except  Exception  as e:
        print(e.message)
        return e.message
```

#### Result before deployed in azure

[image]

#### After Deployed in Azure

Deployed through VS Code. Make sure all your required packages are deployed in azure.

[image]

Web App response.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply @Delliganesh Sevanesan. I will try modifying your sample code to meet my needs.

Comment: It turns out that 1) my `path` was not created correctly 2) `CONNECTION_STRING` was not  read properly from the Azure App Settings using `os.environ.get("AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING")
`, contrarily to what I initially thought.

Comment: Although it did not directly fix my problem, your code sample is a nice MRE, so I am accepting your answer and upvoting it. Thanks again for your help!